# What do you call the bolded part of the movie's title?

Tags: terminology

What do you call the bolded part of the movie's title?

For example:

> Predator: **The Last Stand**

What do you call the bolded part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [subtitle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(titling)):

> In books and other works, a subtitle is an explanatory or alternate title. [...] A more modern usage is to simply separate the subtitle by punctuation, making the subtitle more of a continuation or sub-element of the title proper.

They give the example *Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest* of a movie with a subtitle.

Yes, this is a bit confusing considering the other meaning of *subtitle*, so in the rare case you’d need to refer to half the title, you’ll need to use context to make it clear what you mean.